# Can some explain why this won't draw a circle? It is drawing roughly 3/4

Tags: python

If we want to use n small lines to outline our circle then we can just divide both the circumference and 360 degrees by n (i.e , (2*pi*r)/n and 360/n).

Did I not do that? When I run this, it draws roughly 3/4 of a circle.

```
import turtle, math

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('blue')

body = turtle.Turtle()
body.pencolor('black')
body.fillcolor('white')
body.speed(10)
body.width(3)
body.hideturtle()
body.up()
body.goto(0, 200)

lines = 40

toprad = 40

top_circum = 2 * math.pi * toprad

sol = top_circum / lines
circle = 360 / lines

for stops in range(lines):
    body.pendown()
    body.left(sol)
    body.forward(circle)


window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: @occulus, he gets 3/4 of a circle

Comment: Yeah, just saw that in the title, moved into body.

Comment: Why did you remove your post?

Comment: Lol I am not sure what happend? I think my account is hacked or something? It just did the same thing on another post. I can repost if you would like. I just looked in my clipboard and that sentence isnt even in there lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better named variables might help!

I think you've mixed two of your variables up. I think your code should read:

```
for stops in range(lines):
    body.pendown()
    body.left(circle)    // swapped vars 
    body.forward(sol)    // on these two lines
```

Basically, by mixing up the vars, you were rotating by the amount you should have moved your pen forwards, and vice versa.

For more readable code that would make it harder to make this sort of mistake, I suggest renaming your vars something like this:

```
circle --> penForwardAmount
sol    --> penRotateAmount
lines  --> numberOfLines
```

and finally, delete the `topRad` variable and use `numLines` whereever you had used `topRad`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was baffled. I am trying to teach myself. Good call on the terrible variable names too. I've been at this for the last few hours and haven't went to bed yet my brain is melting. I think that maybe sleeping is a programmer's best friend.

Comment: :) It's correct what they say about sleep deprivation temporarily lowering your IQ! Sleep is good.

Comment: And kudos for you for deciding to teach yourself programming.